# Advice on learning mathematics

Tags: education, self-learning

I know it is hard to ask for the perfect method for doing mathematics, but I hope there are some paths that are more preferable over others. I am a engineering student who has switched to mathematics but I still only have experience with very calculation heavy subjects like differential equations, calculus 1 and 2, ... Today I thought the following, is there a good method to tackle all problems? Reductionism works well in many areas of life, is it a good strategy in mathematics? Or is it a good strategy to always strive for a higher degree of abstraction? Things always seems harder when it is abstract but I think this is the place where relationships between various things are understood.

Comment: I’m skeptical of the idea that much of anything is *always* a good strategy. In practice I may find myself working from either end, or from both.

Comment: @user29163 Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. 

Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!